# The option to save a file is greyed out in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 on Ubuntu. Often, after editing a file, I cannot save it - the "save" option is greyed out in the menu and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> seems to do nothing, even though the file has just been modified and the editor displays the asterisk before the file name in the tab header.

Changing the active tab to another file and then coming back to the first file "unlocks" the save option, which I can then choose.

What causes this behavior, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Same problem here, using i3 as window manager. Happens only after using a bugfix suggestion.

Comment: Ok, fixed in the latest dev branch in i3 and now works for me. Seems like a problem of the windowmanager...

Comment: Interesting, I do have a similar problem with e17 windowmanager, which is not broadly used to. @Oak: are you using a rare wm to ?

Comment: @fanf42 I use the regular gnome WM.

Comment: +1 for the changing the active tab to another file hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reported bug in Eclipse.  You can follow up and bring more information in [the bug report in Eclipse's bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362561).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest workaround I could find was to just restart eclipse. Worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The questioner has asked for a fix and I have given a solution that is a fix that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

That can also happen when the **Project Explorer** view has focus ([bug 211520](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=211520))

The new [Eclipse 2019-09 has fixed that issue](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/platform.php#save-action-project-explorer)

> You can now save the active editor even when the Project Explorer has focus.
>
> In cases where an extension contributes Saveables to the Project Explorer, the extension is honored and the save action on the Project Explorer will save the provided saveable item instead of the active editor.

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/images/save_project_explorer.png]